# Pinned debugger variables are wrong

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

[image: Debugger Picture Visual Studio 2015]

## The Problem

Right now i'm using visual basic 2015. My problem is that the debugs I pin shows the wrong variables. And current objects shouldn't even be able to get a player tag. If I hold over current object I get the right variables, but I would really like to have the pinned ones with right variables. So I can have a better overview over what is happening.

**Edit: I have edited the code, so the code is different from when the problem occurred. It still pins the wrong variables. The problem does not happen in Visual Studio 2017**

## Debugging Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class ObjectPlacement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public GameObject[] objects;
    public GameObject[] plants; //different plants that can be planted. 
    private PlaceableObject placeableObject;    //Check if other objects are in the way.
    public Transform asteroid;
    private Transform currentObject;    //The object the player is interacting with.
    private PlayerInventory inventory;  //To get seeds and what tool is being used
    private HighlightObject hi; //Change which object that is highlighted
    public float clickTimer = 0.2f; //Prevents the player to click to fast and from instantly planting
    private float clickTimerReset;  //Keeps the value of the original clicktimer
    private bool hasPlaced; //prevents double planting
    public Animator animController; 
    private bool clickReady;    //Prevents instantly planting

    private void Start()
    {
        clickTimerReset = clickTimer;
        inventory = GetComponent<PlayerInventory>();
        animController = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!clickReady)   //Prevents the player for planting by accident if the click to fast.
        {
            clickTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (clickTimer < 0)
                clickReady = true;
        }

        Debug.Log("CurrentObject = " + currentObject);
        if (currentObject != null && !hasPlaced)    //True if a object is currently being placed
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);    //Coordinates to where the object will be placed.
            GetComponent<InteractObject>().SetCurrentObject(currentObject.gameObject);  //Sets currentObject in the InteractObject script to show plants area of effect.
            currentObject.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;  //Can rotate the plant with the players rotation. Quickfix

            if ((inventory.currentTool != PlayerInventory.Tool.Free) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))    //Cancels the placement
            {
                animController.SetTrigger("CancelPlanting");
                GetComponent<InteractObject>().SetPlanting(false);  //Makes interactive object script able to change currentObject.
                hi.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.Normal);    //Object set to normal material.
                inventory.AddToInventory(currentObject.GetComponent<Seed>().GetSeedType(), 1);  //Put seed back to the inventory.
                Destroy(currentObject.gameObject);
                GetComponent<InteractObject>().SetCurrentObject(null);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                hasPlaced = true;
                currentObject = null;
            }
            else if ((inventory.GetSelectedSeed() != currentObject.GetComponent<Seed>().seedType) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))   //When changing a seed.
            {
                animController.SetTrigger("CancelPlanting");
                GetComponent<InteractObject>().SetPlanting(false);  //Makes interactive object script able to change currentObject.
                hi.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.Normal);    //Object set to normal material.
                inventory.AddToInventory(currentObject.GetComponent<Seed>().GetSeedType(), 1);  //Put seed back to the inventory.
                Destroy(currentObject.gameObject);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                GetComponent<InteractObject>().SetCurrentObject(null);
                currentObject = null;
                hasPlaced = true;
            }

            Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 20, Color.green); //shows the ray in editor window.

            if (IsLegalPosition())  //If there is no obstacles in the way, the plant is green and can be planted.
                hi.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.Highlight);
            else
                hi.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.NotAvailable);  //There is a obstacle in the way and the plant cannot be planted. 

            RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, 20);    //Collects all the object the ray hits in a list.

            foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
            {
                if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Asteroid"))
                {
                    if (currentObject != null)
                        currentObject.transform.position = hit.point;
                }

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && clickReady) //plant with a click. Also prevents instaplant
                {
                    if (IsLegalPosition())
                    {
                        animController.SetTrigger("PlantingPlant");
                        currentObject.GetComponent<BasePlant>().Planted();  //Starts the plants growth
                        currentObject.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Interactable"); //changes the layer from IgnoreRaycast to Interactable.
                        hi.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.Normal);
                        hasPlaced = true;
                        hi.SetHologram(false);
                        hi = null;
                        currentObject = null;
                        Cursor.visible = false;
                        MouseClicked();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    //Checks if there is something in the way
    private bool IsLegalPosition()
    {
        foreach (var item in placeableObject.colliders)
        {
            if (item.tag == "Plant")
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets an object in front of the player
    /// </summary>
    public void UseObject(GameObject _object)
    {
        if (currentObject == null)
        {
            if (inventory.useSeed(_object.GetComponent<Seed>().seedType))    //Won't make the object unless the it has the used seed in the inventory
            {
                hasPlaced = false;                                              //checks that the object hasen't been placed yet
                Cursor.visible = true;
                animController.SetTrigger("PlacingPlant");
                currentObject = ((GameObject)Instantiate(_object)).transform;       //The object that is about to be placed
                placeableObject = currentObject.GetComponent<PlaceableObject>();    //To check if the object is colliding with other objects.
                hi = currentObject.GetComponent<HighlightObject>();                 //Makes the code abit tidier. TIDYBOYS ONTZ ONTZ ONTZ
                hi.SetHologram(true);                                        //Makes the object turn into a hologram.
                MouseClicked();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a timer which prevents an object to be set after a mouseclick.
    /// </summary>
    public void MouseClicked()
    {
        clickTimer = clickTimerReset;
        clickReady = false;
    }



    public void SetObject(Seed.Type type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Seed.Type.Normal:
                UseObject(plants[0]);
                break;
            case Seed.Type.Shield:
                UseObject(plants[1]);
                break;
            case Seed.Type.Water:
                UseObject(plants[2]);
                break;
            case Seed.Type.Light:
                UseObject(plants[3]);
                break;
            case Seed.Type.Fruit:
                UseObject(plants[4]);
                break;
            case Seed.Type.None:
                return;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    //Incase we ever would need a fixed planting pos again.
    //Ray ray = new Ray();    //Creates a new ray
    //Vector3 direction = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rayDegree, transform.right) * -transform.up;   //Getting the direction of the ray
    //Vector3 RayStartPos = transform.up * 2 + transform.forward * 0.2f;  //Because vectors is according to world space.
    //ray.direction = direction;  //Setting the direction to the ray
    //ray.origin = transform.position + RayStartPos;  //Setting the startpoint of the ray
}
```

## Additional Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Assertions;

public class InteractObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material radiusMaterial;
    public Camera cam;                  //cam the raycast comes from
    public bool clicked;                //if an object is clicked
    private PlayerInventory inventory;  //Get the players inventory.
    private bool planting;  //To prevent currentObject from changing while planting.

    //For interactable zone and editor
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float viewRadius; //The radius of the circle that determines the interactable zone
    [Range(0, 360)]
    public float viewAngle; //The angle between the lines, determining the interactable zone
    public LayerMask interactable; //The layerMask we want the code to care about

    public List<Collider> interactableObjects = new List<Collider>(); //A list of all interactable objects in range
    public GameObject closestObject; //Holds the interactable object closest to the character, if any are in range
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject currentObject; //The object the mouse hovers over.
    public GameObject mainManager; //Need to access the main manager
    private Animator animController;

    private HighlightObject tempHighlight;
    private HighlightObject.Type oldStatus;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all the components needed from scratch
    /// </summary>
    void Awake()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
        mainManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Manager");
        inventory = GetComponent<PlayerInventory>();
        animController = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //FIX HERE, TILEPLANT BASED
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!planting)   //Won't change currentObject if the player is planting. Prevents the radius from changing its object.
            FindInteractableObjects();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            UseTool();  //Uses current held tool
        }
        if (currentObject != null)
        {
            radiusMaterial.SetVector("_Center", currentObject.transform.position);  //The coordinates of the radius center on the ground for the shader.
            SetRadius();    //Sets the radius according to plant and plant type.
        }
        else
            HideRadius();   //Sets the radius width to 0 so its invisible.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all interactable objects within the interactable area of the player. This area is restricted by the 
    /// viewRadius and viewAngle variables, and is visible in the unity editor. 
    /// It then saves these interactable objects in a list that can be accessed throughout the script.
    /// </summary>
    void FindInteractableObjects()
    {
        interactableObjects.Clear();    //Clears the list

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);    //Shoots a ray to the center of the screen from the camera.
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, 15);    //Saves all the objects the ray hits in a list
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 30f, Color.blue); //Shows a ray in the editor window
        foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)    //checks if the hit is a plant
        {
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Plant"))
            {
                currentObject = hit.collider.gameObject;    //Sets current object to a hit.
                SetRadius();    //Sets the radius of the effects of the plant
                break;
            }
        }

        #region Highlight object
        if ((tempHighlight != null) && (tempHighlight.gameObject != currentObject))  //Sets the highlight of the object on change.
        {
            tempHighlight.SetMaterial(oldStatus);   //Sets the old current objects status to what it was.
            tempHighlight = currentObject.GetComponent<HighlightObject>();  //Sets th to the newly selected object.
            oldStatus = tempHighlight.getStatus();  //Gets the status to change back to when changing the plant.
            if (oldStatus == HighlightObject.Type.Highlight)    //This is not allowed.
                oldStatus = HighlightObject.Type.Normal;
            tempHighlight.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.Highlight);  //Highlights the newly currentObject.
        }
        else if (tempHighlight == null && currentObject != null) //Highlights the objects. 
        {
            tempHighlight = currentObject.GetComponent<HighlightObject>();  //sets the currentObject.
            oldStatus = tempHighlight.getStatus();  //Saves the old status to change back to
            tempHighlight.SetMaterial(HighlightObject.Type.Highlight);  //Highlights the currentObject.
        }
        #endregion
        //closestObject = null;
        Collider[] interactableObjectsInRange = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, viewRadius, interactable);    //KAYERS EXPLAIN

        foreach (Collider value in interactableObjectsInRange)
        {
            Vector3 dirToTarget = value.transform.position - transform.position; 
            if (Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, dirToTarget) < viewAngle / 2)
                interactableObjects.Add(value);

            if (value.CompareTag("Seed"))   //Picks up a seed
            {
                Seed.Type _seedtype = value.GetComponent<Seed>().seedType;
                inventory.AddToInventory(_seedtype, 1); //Adds the relevant seed to the inventory
                Destroy(value.gameObject);
            }
            else if (value.CompareTag("Collectable"))   //Picks up a collectable like Fruit
            {
                Sellables item = value.GetComponent<Sellables>();
                inventory.AddToInventory(item, 1);   //Adds collectable to the inventory.
                Destroy(value.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    private void UseTool()
    {
        switch (inventory.currentTool)
        {
            case PlayerInventory.Tool.Free:
                planting = true;
                GetComponent<ObjectPlacement>().SetObject(inventory.GetSelectedSeed()); //Plants a plant with current selected seed
                //GetComponent<ObjectPlacement>().MouseClicked(); //Delay on the mouseclick to prevent accidently fast plantig.
                break;

            case PlayerInventory.Tool.Shovel:

                planting = false;
                HideRadius();   //Hides the material radius.
                if (currentObject != null && currentObject.CompareTag("Plant"))
                {
                    BasePlant SelecetedPlant = currentObject.GetComponent<BasePlant>();     //Makes code prettier
                    if (SelecetedPlant.fullgrown)
                        SelecetedPlant.HarvestPlant(1); //Plant drop two seeds since it is fullgrown.
                    else
                    {
                        SelecetedPlant.killPlant(1);    //Plants disseappear
                        inventory.AddToInventory(SelecetedPlant.GetPlantType(), 1); //Drops one seed
                    }

                    animController.SetTrigger("Harvesting");
                    tempHighlight = null;   //Removes gameobject to prevent bugs
                    currentObject = null;   // Ditto
                }
                break;

            case PlayerInventory.Tool.Watercan:
                {
                    animController.SetTrigger("Watering");
                    if (interactableObjects != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Collider col in interactableObjects)   //Go through the interactable list and and waters the plants.
                        {
                            if (col.CompareTag("Plant"))
                            {
                                col.gameObject.GetComponent<BasePlant>().WaterPlant();  //Waters the Plant.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    HideRadius();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //Adds a seed that is picked up to the inventory.
    private void PickUpSeed(Seed.Type sendIn)
    {
        inventory.AddToInventory(sendIn, 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the radius for the plants area of effect
    /// </summary>
    private void SetRadius()
    {
        Seed.Type sType = currentObject.GetComponent<Seed>().GetSeedType(); //To get the right plant
        float _radius = 0;  //If the plant does not have a radius it won't be seen.
        Color color = Color.blue;   //Waterplants natural color since local variables need to be set to something.
        bool radiusPlant = true;    //True if the selected plant have a radius.
        switch (sType)  //Sets the type of the radius
        {
            case Seed.Type.Shield:
                radiusMaterial.SetFloat("_RadiusWidth", 0.2f);
                _radius = currentObject.GetComponent<ShieldPlant>().radius; //Gets the plants radius.
                color = Color.magenta;
                break;
            case Seed.Type.Water:
                radiusMaterial.SetFloat("_RadiusWidth", 0.2f);
                _radius = currentObject.GetComponent<WaterPlant>().radius;
                break;
            case Seed.Type.Light:
                radiusMaterial.SetFloat("_RadiusWidth", 0.2f);
                _radius = currentObject.GetComponent<LightPlant>().radius;
                color = Color.yellow;
                break;
            default:
                radiusMaterial.SetFloat("_RadiusWidth", 0);
                radiusPlant = false;
                break;
        }
        if(radiusPlant)
        {
            radiusMaterial.SetColor("_RadiusColor", color);
            radiusMaterial.SetFloat("_Radius", _radius);
        }
    }

    //Hides the circle
    private void HideRadius()
    {
        radiusMaterial.SetFloat("_RadiusWidth", 0);
    }

    //Sets the planting mode from a differente script : ObjectPlacement
    public void SetPlanting(bool set)
    {
        planting = set;
    }

    //Sets current object from another script : ObjectPlacement
    public void SetCurrentObject(GameObject setObject)
    {
        currentObject = setObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't say "Visual Studio 15" if you mean Visual Studio 2015. There are marketing names for Visual Studio and Version Numbers, and apart from the coincidence that was Visual Studio 2010 (version 10), the numbers are *not* aligned. Visual Studio 15 is what is "marketed" as Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio 17 does not yet exist and we won't expect it for quite some time.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Edited it now

Comment: Debug vs. release mode?

Comment: @Paul_87 "And current objects shouldn't even be able to get a player tag" - what does this mean? Every `GameObject` has a `tag` field. Do you mean that the field should remain `"Untagged"` instead of having a specific tag?

Comment: @Galandil Sorry for being unclear. currentObject is tagged with "Player" in debugger mode. which is not supposed to happen. But if I hold over currentObject as seen to the left on the picture, it is set to "Plant" which is right. But on the pin to the right it is set to "Player"
        
foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
        {
            if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Plant"))
            {
                currentObject = hit.collider.gameObject;
                SetRadius();
                break;
            }
        }
Nowhere else in the script is currentObject set.

Comment: This is getting messy: please post all the relevant code and explain in detail what are you trying to achieve and what is going wrong.

Comment: @Galandil So sorry, first time I use stack overflow. I just want to know why the watched variables are showing a different value than the objects value.

Comment: You may share a screenshot with complete code and the relevant variables which could help us to understand your issue better.Thanks.

Comment: @FletchZhou-MSFT Thank you, I will have to check with my teacher about uploading the code. Since it is for our bachelors degree it's really strict rules. I really hoped I just used the debugger wrong. Thank you all for trying and being so helpful.

Comment: @Paul_87 Any update of this issue please?